# Prove that $D$ is an ideal of $^\bullet \mathbb R$ using limsup

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, synthetic-differential-geometry

I read about model construction in synthetic differential geometry
(http://www.iam.fmph.uniba.sk/amuc/_vol-73/_no_2/_giordano/giordano.pdf)

I try to understand Theorem 1.1 and its proof, but I can't.

Can anyone explain why do we use limsup to prove that $D$ is an ideal and every element of $D$ has square equal to zero?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: `Can anyone explain why do we use limsup to prove that  is an ideal` how are you going to test membership in the ideal if you don't use the definition of membership?  As for your other question, I personally don't know which elementary properties of limsup the author is using. It "looks" like maybe they're changing $|\frac{h(t)^2}{t}|$ to $|h(t)||\frac{h(t)}{t}|$ and then taking the limsup of both but I would have guessed that wasn't valid.  I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Note that Giordano's theory is different from Synthetic Differential Geometry, and in fact he uses a different notation for his line, as you can see in the jpg reproduced in the *question*.  @rschwieb

Comment: @MikhailKatz I want to ask. In the jpg above it was written that "x is close to y. We obtain a well-defined congruence on *R that coincides with equality on R". Does it mean that $x$ infinitesimally close to $y$? And does equality on $R$ mean that $x(0)=y(0)$? Thanks.

Comment: Giordano uses the term "close" for the relation of infinite proximity.  The usual real numbers are embedded in his ring via constant functions.  As usual, if two real numbers are infinitely close, then they are equal.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Does $h$ is close to $0$ mean that $h$ is less than any real numbers? (as is indistinguishable from zero in SDG)?

Comment: @Mike_bb, no, Giordano is working with classical logic.  His infinitesimals are nilpotent simply because he quotients out by squares.  As a result, his number system is only a ring, not a field, and there is no transfer principle.

Comment: @MikhailKatz ok. I can't understand. What does $h$ equal then? If $h \in D$ then how is it possible that $h$ isn't less than any real number?

Comment: @Mike_bb, Giordano looks at the asymptotic behavior of a function $h(t)$ when $t$ tends to $0$.  For example, if $h(t)=t$, then $h$ defines a first-order infinitesimal in  his ring.  It is smaller than every positive real number $r$ because for $t$ small enough, it will be less than $r$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz It is what I meant above. Thanks :)

Comment: @MikhailKatz I'm not trying to be difficult when saying this, but I don't understand what your first comment above has to do with what I wrote.  In my mind, limsup comes from ordinary real analysis (that could be a mistake), but I do not know what it means for "Synthetic differential geometry" which was not on my mind. You refer to a line in the jpeg in the *question* (italicized for some reason?  I only worked with this jpeg...) but I'm not sure what line you are referring to.  Can you clarify what you mean, or better yet explain what properties the author is alluding to?

Comment: Giordano uses limsup rather than lim because he does not want to require the existence of the limit as $t\to0$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz You wrote that $h(t)=t$ and $h$ defines first-order infinitesimal. In our case (if $t$ small enough then it will be less than $r$) $h$ must have value but if $h^2=0$ then $h$ is quality that has no value. How is it possible if we approximate $h$ with $t$?

Comment: Here $h$ is just the function $h(t)$ viewed as representing an element of Giordano's quotient ring.  Its square is zero simply because Giordano quotients by it when defining his ring.  It's not that $h^2$ has no value.  It does: the value $0$ in the quotient ring.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I didn't mean $h^2$, I meant that $h$ has no value.

Comment: Here $h$ is the function $h(t)=t$ and we are interested in its behavior when $t$ tends to zero.  For this reason, it becomes an infinitesimal in the ring, when compared to any positive *constant* function.  Its "value" in the quotient ring will be its equivalence class in the ring.  I think you need to review quotient ring constructions.

Comment: @MikhailKatz  Ok. Why can't this infinitesimal be $1/inf$ as Leibniz infinitesimal?

Comment: Because Giordano is defining a *ring*, not a *field*.  He simply chooses not to include inverses.  Otherwise he can't get nilsquare infinitesimals, as you point out.

Comment: @MikhailKatz This infinitesimal is slightly similar to $\varepsilon = (1/2, 1/4, 1/8,...)$ in hyperreal numbers, isn't it?

Comment: In fact one can obtain a ring similar to Giordano's by taking the ring of finite hyperreals, choosing a fixed infinitesimal $\varepsilon$ there, and quotienting the ring out by $\varepsilon^2$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Ok. Are such infinitesimals positive in IDG? Can we conclude that such infinitesimal is nilpotent from $\varepsilon^2=0$ and can we say that infinitesimals are indintistiguishable from zero or can't?

Comment: The concept of "indistinguishability" only exists when the background logic is intuitionistic.  Giordano is working with classical logic, when numbers are either zero or not.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Thanks! I understand it.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Hello. I read more about Cauchy sequences and I saw multiplication rule: (Xn) × (Yn) = (Xn × Yn). Therefore (h(t)) × (h(t)) = ((h(t)×(h(t)) = $h^2$ In our case $h \approx 0$ but $h^2=0$. This breaks the multiplication rule. How is it possible?